# Check if byte stored as string of bits is set at a given position

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I have a string representing a byte or string of bits e.g "10011111". I want convert it to a bitarray and check if a bit is set at any given position e.g at position 3.
When i try convert that string to a byte it gives me a 
    "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."          Convert.ToByte(reader[1].ToString()). Value of reader[1].ToString() = "11111111".

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the *base* explicitly, which is ***2*** in your case:

```
 Byte result = Convert.ToByte(reader[1].ToString(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
string x = "111111000";

var cd = x.ToCharArray();
```

and then you can work accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The conversion used by `Convert.ToByte` is using a decimal numeric system. An easy way to convert to a binary array using Linq would be:

```
bool[] array = "101001010101".Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();
```

Or to conserve memory:

```
string str = "1010101001011100";
var array = new BitArray(str.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = str[i] == '1';
}
```

Or just use the string itself:

```
bool isSet = str[3] == '1';
```